# Class 'mPDF' not found - kartik gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

i'm using kartik gridview for export to pdf, and i need help to resolve this problem.

When I export to pdf yii2 return: 
"PHP Fatal Error"

"Class 'mPDF' not found"

```
public function setApi()
{
    $this->_mpdf = new mPDF(
        $this->mode,
        $this->format,
        $this->defaultFontSize,
        $this->defaultFont,
        $this->marginLeft,
        $this->marginRight,
        $this->marginTop,
        $this->marginBottom,
        $this->marginHeader,
```

Gridview options:

```
'exportConfig' => [
            GridView::PDF => [
                'config' => [
                    'contentBefore' => '<b> XXX - YYYY </b>',
                    'contentAfter'  => '<a href="#">Test</a>',
                ],
            ],
```

Installed components: vendor/mpdf/mpdf and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf.

Could someone help me solve this? Sorry for my English.

Comment: import vendor/mpdf/mpdf;

Answer (score 0):

kartik-v/yii2-mpdf requires mpdf/mpdf
try 
    `composer require mpdf/mpdf "*"`
after or before installing kartik-v/yii2-mpdf